# How do I translate the term 'Happy Path' without losing some of the meaning?

Tags: english-to-german

I am writing a documentation that includes implemented test cases. In this context I need to translate the term 'Happy Path'.

For the sake of this question I will go with the [Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_path) of the term:

> In the context of software or information modeling, a happy path is a default scenario featuring no exceptional or error conditions, and comprises nothing if everything goes as expected.

I tried the following translations:

**glücklicher Weg**

This sounds rather like a path through a cannabis field than a description of the test case.

**Standard-Weg**

While this is better, it does not seem to convey the absence of error conditions.

Is there a similar term in German that I could use?

Comment: In my documentation, I always call this "Normalverhalten" (normal behaviour). It's not about path in test cases, but it fits the Wikipedia-definition.

Comment: Since the wikipedia article uses the term 'scenario' one could use a translation based on this. "Standardszenario" or "Wunschszenario" come into my mind.

Comment: Another expression that relates to "Happy Path" would be *Sunny Day Scenario" - I have seen this translated to "Sonntagsszenario" in places, but found it to be a bit uncommon.

Comment: Analog zu @tofro: Schönwetterflug

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ich denke, eine akzeptable (und dabei unauffällige) Form, in gutem Deutsch einen "happy path" zu bezeichnen, wäre der schlichte, alte

> Idealfall

Etwa so:

> Im Idealfall läuft das Programm glatt durch ohne besondere Vorkommnisse, ohne Macken und Hänger.

Ich muss aber zugeben, dass man sich daran reiben kann, dass der *Idealfall* in der Regel ja abstrakt verstanden wird, nicht in einer so konkreten Bedeutung wie bei einem "happy path" oder auch "sunny day scenario", und dass darum eine so konkrete Verwendung des Worts *Idealfall* nicht der... äh... Idealfall ist.

Möchte man diese Reibung vermeiden, könnte man vielleicht sagen:

> **In Standardsituationen** läuft das Programm glatt durch. Aber es ist noch nicht gegen alle Eventualitäten gewappnet, das heißt, bei ungewöhnlichen Ausgangs-Parametern kann es noch abstürzen.

Oder auch:

> **Im Normalfall** ist das Programm stabil. Aber sobald etwas nicht ganz nach Schema F läuft, kommt es ins Trudeln.

Oder umgekehrt:

> Ist alles **nach Schema F**, läuft das Programm stabil. Aber wenn ungewöhnlichere Werte auftreten, saust es uns noch ab.

Und zu guter Letzt (nach mehrfachem stillen Wiederkäuen des ja eigentlich ganz netten *sunny day scenario*) hier nun endlich eine saubere und hoffentlich befriedigende Lösung:

> **Unter Schönwetterbedingungen** ist das Programm stabil. Aber die leichteste Variation der Ausgangswerte kann uns den Ablauf verhageln.

(Da hätte man auch gleich drauf kommen können...)

Comment: *Idealfall* is a bit different - It takes the results of your software into account and hopes everything is as expected. A "happy day scenario" mainly relates to the assumption that all input data is according to the common requirements and the piece of software receives exactly the input it expects. The opposite would be "rainy day scenario" where the software is tested to reject incomplete or wrong (or generally, unexpected) input. *Idealfall* does not exactly refer to this, IMHO - One would need to extend with "Ideale Eingangsdaten" or the like.

Comment: "Gutwetterbedingung" ist schon ganz nett. Aber warum nicht "Schönwetterbedingungen"? Das wäre zumindestens mir geläufiger, denn ich habe auch schon von "Schönwettersoftware" gehört.

Comment: Richtig! Schönwetterbedingungen heißt das!

Comment: Und **jetzt** kriegste auch ein +1 von mir! - Aber nur für die *Schönwetterbedingungen*. Die *Standardsituationen* hören sich mir zu stark nach Fußball an, den *Normalfall* habe ich oben beim *Idealfall* schon kommentiert und *Schema F.* ist mir zu aussagelos.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the term

> Gutfall

While seldom used, see discussion [here](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/De/de.etc.sprache.deutsch/2010-01/msg01582.html), I would consider it as technical term for exactly this.

Comment: Please, don't use that. It's a real pain to read.

Answer (score -1):

A default scenario is a working scenario, and any working scenario is a

> [Fallbeispiel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Fallbeispiel)